# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta' while changing models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am attempting to restructure my database models to include more data than `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. However, making the changes to `models.py` and `views.py`, then running `python manage.py makemigrations` doesn't properly update my migrations. Apparently, Django still thinks I'm using a proxy model.

I had to change `users/migrations/0001_initial.py` to avoid a dependency error, then I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and got `No changes detected`.

`users/migrations/0001_initial.py` **(before changes)**

```py
# Generated by Django 2.2 on 2019-05-01 03:13

from django.db import migrations
import users.managers


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Person',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'proxy': True,
                'constraints': [],
                'indexes': [],
            },
            bases=('auth.user',),
            managers=[
                ('objects', users.managers.PersonManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

`users/migrations/0001_initial.py` **(after changes)**

```py
# Generated by Django 2.2 on 2019-05-01 03:13

from django.db import migrations
import users.managers


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = []

    operations = []
```

`users/models.py` **(before changes)**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import managers

class Person(User):
    objects = managers.PersonManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

`users/models.py` **(after changes)**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users import managers

class Profile:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    objects = managers.ProfileManager()
```

`users/views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import Profile

def index(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_pk=request.session['id']) \
        if 'id' in request.session else None

    return render(request, 'users/index.html', {
        'profile': profile,
    })


def login(request):
    valid, response = Profile.objects.login_register(request, 'login')

    if not valid:
        for error in response:
            messages.error(request, error)
        return redirect('users:index')

    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=response)
    messages.success(request, 'Welcome back, %s!' % profile.user.first_name)
    request.session['id'] = response
    return redirect('users:index')


def register(request):
    valid, response = Profile.objects.login_register(request, 'register')

    if not valid:
        for error in response:
            messages.error(request, error)
        return redirect('users:index')

    messages.success(request, 'You have successfully created an account.')
    request.session['id'] = response
    return redirect('users:index')


def logout(request):
    del request.session['id']

    messages.success(request, 'You have successfully logged out.')
    return redirect('users:index')
```

When I try to login or register, I expect the page to reload with the login/registration form changed to the user's profile page.

**Error message**

```
Internal Server Error: /profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/users/views.py", line 12, in index
    if 'id' in request.session else None
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1190, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1049, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/pharmasseuse/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 297, in get_meta
    return self.model._meta
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea to change in migrations files. You can do the changes in model directly, and after changing the model, run [**`./manage.py makemigrations`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) to generate new migration files.

Also, you need to subclass the model class from `models.Model`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    objects = managers.ProfileManager()
```

#### Update

(from comments) As your manager has been changed, I think you can proceed with either one of the following solutions:

1. Keep both `ProfileManager` and `PersonManager` in `users.manager`, then run `makemigrations`.
2. Update the migration file like this(remove managers attribute from dictionary):

```
# Generated by Django 2.2 on 2019-05-01 03:13

from django.db import migrations
import users.managers


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Person',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'proxy': True,
                'constraints': [],
                'indexes': [],
            },
            bases=('auth.user',),
            # managers=[
            #     ('objects', users.managers.PersonManager()),
            # ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: I added the subclass, but I am still having issues. Leaving the migrations file as is throws `AttributeError: module 'users.managers' has no attribute 'PersonManager'` when I run `python manage.py makemigrations`. The issue is that the previous migrations file contains a reference to `PersonManager`, but `PersonManager` was replaced with `ProfileManager`.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy please see the update section of the answer